# How to force a specific dependency version in a gradle buildscript

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

There's an [issue](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/467) for the gradle-docker-plugin and SpringBootVersion 2.0.0.M4
M4 uses a newer jersey client and using the docker-plugin ends in an Exception:

```
ERROR com.github.dockerjava.core.async.ResultCallbackTemplate - Error during callback
java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lambda$lookupInjectionManagerFactory$0(Injections.java:98)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupInjectionManagerFactory(Injections.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:357)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.POSTCallbackNotifier.response(POSTCallbackNotifier.java:29)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.AbstractCallbackNotifier.call(AbstractCallbackNotifier.java:50)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.AbstractCallbackNotifier.call(AbstractCallbackNotifier.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My BuildScript in my main project:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "2.0.0.M4"
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}
....
```

As you can see, we load the spring-boot-gradle-plugin version=2.0.0.M4 and all its dependencies.

My subproject build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply from: "docker.gradle"
....
```

Most important the docker.gradle file in the same directory as the build.gradle of the subproject:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.0.11'
    }
}

apply plugin: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.DockerRemoteApiPlugin

import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.*
...
task buildImage(type: DockerBuildImage, dependsOn: copyDockerFiles) {
    version.release = true
    dockerFile = file("${projectDir}/build/docker/Dockerfile")
    inputDir = file("${projectDir}/build/docker")
    tags = ['...']
}
```

My Questions:
How do I know which Version of the jersey client loads SpringBoot 2.0.0.M4?
How do I force gradle in docker.gradle to use a specific version of the jersey client?
Adding to the classpath didn't work. I think gradle will just use the newest version, which will be loaded by SpringBoot 2.0.0.M4

Answer (score 1):

I simply did:-

```
dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
        classpath "org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.14"
        classpath ( group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text'){
           version{
               strictly '1.10.0'
           }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following in your build.gradle dependencies as pointed in: [This Link](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/467#issuecomment-335608600)

```
dockerJava 'com.nirima:docker-java-shaded:0.16.2'
dockerJava 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.5'
dockerJava 'cglib:cglib:3.2.0'
```

After that you have to separate "buildImage" and "tagImage" tasks as suggested in [This link](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/467#issuecomment-339102065)

I have tested this with: spring boot 2.0.0.M6